# Please help me to fit this table

Tags: tables, longtable, landscape, sidebyside

I am trying to form such kind of table for my thesis.

[Link to Dropbox docx file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tlkuosli3268kt5/Table%207.docx?dl=0)%
Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{p{4.045em}cccccccccc}
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}[4]{*}{VARIABLES} & \multicolumn{2}{p{8.09em}}{\textbf{Healthcare decisions}} & \multicolumn{2}{p{8.09em}}{\textbf{Social decisions}} & \multicolumn{2}{p{8.09em}}{\textbf{Consumption decisions}} & \multicolumn{2}{p{8.09em}}{\textbf{Financial decisions}} & \multicolumn{2}{p{8.09em}}{\textbf{All decisions}} \\
\cmidrule{2-11}    \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{\textbf{(Parity≤ 3)}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{\textbf{(Parity> 3)}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{\textbf{(Parity≤ 3)}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{\textbf{(Parity> 3)}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{\textbf{(Parity≤ 3)}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{\textbf{(Parity> 3)}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{\textbf{(Parity≤ 3)}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{\textbf{(Parity> 3)}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{\textbf{(Parity≤ 3)}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{\textbf{(Parity> 3)}} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{9}{p{36.405em}}{\textbf{Sons (ref: none)}}               &       &  \\
    At least one son & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.156***(0.059)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.088(0.228)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.224***(0.063)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.057(0.240)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.168***(0.064)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.134(0.152)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.020(0.068)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.175(0.214)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.226***(0.076)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.205(0.238)} \\
    \textbf{Age} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.026***(0.004)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.018***(0.004)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.030***(0.004)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.024***(0.005)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.031***(0.004)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.024***(0.005)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.007*(0.004)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.003(0.005)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.012***(0.005)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.019***(0.006)} \\
    \textbf{Age difference} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.016***(0.005)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.002(0.005)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.023***(0.005)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.003(0.005)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.016***(0.005)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.003(0.005)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.004(0.005)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.001(0.005)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.003(0.006)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.001(0.006)} \\
    \multicolumn{9}{p{36.405em}}{\textbf{Women education (ref: none)}}    &       &  \\
    Primary & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.056(0.074)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.083(0.068)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.076(0.085)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.247***(0.081)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.036(0.086)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.044(0.075)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.006(0.111)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.120(0.089)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.097(0.109)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.161*(0.095)} \\
    Secondary & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.335***(0.087)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.162(0.103)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.239***(0.077)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.030(0.103)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.236***(0.086)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.028(0.106)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.170*(0.100)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.002(0.114)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.328***(0.110)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.219*(0.122)} \\
    Higher & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.653***(0.104)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.028(0.169)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.413***(0.107)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.312**(0.157)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.449***(0.115)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.140(0.158)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.182(0.128)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.181(0.158)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.615***(0.129)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.525***(0.175)} \\
    \multicolumn{11}{p{44.495em}}{\textbf{Spouse education (ref: none)}} \\
    Primary & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.014(0.089)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.235***(0.075)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.068(0.083)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.057(0.073)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.048(0.091)} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{=-0.149*(0.076)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.027(0.092)} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{=-0.154*(0.084)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.031(0.102)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.100(0.081)} \\
    Secondary & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.017(0.073)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.079(0.077)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.042(0.077)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.015(0.076)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.040(0.075)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.018(0.074)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.107(0.077)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.068(0.071)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.072(0.084)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.034(0.085)} \\
    Higher & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.024(0.085)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.035(0.097)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.077(0.094)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.063(0.113)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.087(0.106)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.072(0.120)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.110(0.097)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.103(0.108)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.024(0.104)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.062(0.129)} \\
    \multicolumn{11}{p{44.495em}}{\textbf{Women employed (ref: none)}} \\
    Yes   & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.179**(0.080)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.205***(0.058)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.189**(0.080)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.231***(0.068)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.211***(0.077)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.285***(0.058)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.211***(0.080)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.169**(0.077)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.227**(0.089)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.287***(0.077)} \\
    \multicolumn{11}{p{44.495em}}{\textbf{Media exposure (ref: none)}} \\
    Occasionally & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.219**(0.086)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.044(0.082)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.184**(0.083)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.041(0.084)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.191**(0.082)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.063(0.102)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.222**(0.102)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.007(0.081)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.381***(0.101)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.089(0.085)} \\
    Weekly & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.026(0.162)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.044(0.177)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.173(0.164)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.170(0.185)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.056(0.161)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.199(0.173)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.233(0.200)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.070(0.171)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.039(0.194)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.223(0.219)} \\
    Daily & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.159**(0.080)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.146**(0.073)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.136*(0.076)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.124(0.077)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.161**(0.073)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.184**(0.081)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.138(0.086)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.085(0.075)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.194**(0.094)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.182**(0.083)} \\
    \multicolumn{11}{p{44.495em}}{\textbf{Family structure (ref: joint)}} \\
    Nuclear family & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.358***(0.077)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.129*(0.071)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.485***(0.076)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.319***(0.079)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.450***(0.077)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.233***(0.083)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.101(0.084)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.049(0.102)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.022(0.096)} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{=-0.202*(0.114)} \\
    Household size & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.028***(0.010)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.035***(0.007)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.042***(0.010)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.039***(0.007)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.049***(0.010)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.047***(0.008)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.014(0.009)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.024***(0.008)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.031***(0.009)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.043***(0.010)} \\
    \multicolumn{11}{p{44.495em}}{\textbf{Place of residence (ref: rural)}} \\
    Urban & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.210**(0.082)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.214**(0.083)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.198***(0.073)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.125(0.091)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.220***(0.071)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.129(0.087)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.148(0.092)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.094(0.083)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.211*(0.107)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.077(0.107)} \\
    \multicolumn{11}{p{44.495em}}{\textbf{Province/ Region (ref: Islamabad)}} \\
    Punjab & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.315***(0.092)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.259**(0.110)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.185**(0.084)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.138(0.096)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.207**(0.087)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.099(0.123)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.262**(0.104)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.244**(0.121)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.254**(0.100)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.235(0.147)} \\
    Sindh & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.167(0.102)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.099(0.120)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.050(0.092)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.240**(0.105)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.147(0.100)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.444***(0.127)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.089(0.119)} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{=-0.211*(0.126)} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{=-0.182*(0.101)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.390***(0.149)} \\
    KPK region & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.279**(0.112)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.271**(0.123)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.371***(0.106)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.416***(0.111)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.317***(0.110)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.426***(0.137)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.348***(0.127)} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{=-0.254*(0.133)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.442***(0.114)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.383**(0.153)} \\
    Gilgit-Baltistan & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.064(0.180)} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{=-0.32*(0.186)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.184(0.176)} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{=-0.319*(0.185)} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{=-0.261*(0.133)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.564***(0.175)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.689***(0.155)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.716***(0.173)} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{=-0.356*(0.199)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.584***(0.214)} \\
    Balochistan & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.199(0.150)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.664***(0.146)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.198(0.147)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.836***(0.137)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.219(0.151)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.906***(0.164)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.479***(0.170)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.720***(0.150)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.657***(0.165)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-1.012***(0.173)} \\
    \multicolumn{11}{p{44.495em}}{\textbf{Economic status  (ref: poorest)}} \\
    Poorer & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.206**(0.103)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.208***(0.073)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.238***(0.090)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.193**(0.090)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.225**(0.096)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.224***(0.085)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.335***(0.116)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.298***(0.083)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.206*(0.107)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.146(0.106)} \\
    Middle & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.047(0.109)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.185*(0.105)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.072(0.107)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.202**(0.094)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.093(0.106)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.214**(0.089)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.274**(0.121)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.378***(0.112)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.187(0.120)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.269**(0.104)} \\
    Rich  & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.041(0.119)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.186(0.123)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.048(0.113)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.223**(0.107)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.029(0.113)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.252**(0.106)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.180(0.134)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.281**(0.121)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.156(0.141)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.238*(0.127)} \\
    Richest & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.027(0.149)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.160(0.144)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.070(0.128)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.236*(0.133)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.030(0.130)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.271**(0.134)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.213(0.171)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.335**(0.148)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.244(0.158)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.302*(0.154)} \\
    \textbf{Marginal effect} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.053***(0.020)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.031(0.081)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.073***(0.020)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.019(0.082)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.054***(0.020)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.046(0.053)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.007(0.024)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.063(0.078)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.064***(0.022)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.059(0.072)} \\
    \textbf{Constant} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-1.579***(0.201)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.696**(0.309)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-1.657***(0.194)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.907***(0.307)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-1.634***(0.208)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.856***(0.282)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.498**(0.228)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.283(0.323)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{-0.291(0.209)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{0.012(0.374)} \\
    \textbf{Observations} & 4906  & 5111  & 4909  & 5126  & 4908  & 5118  & 3789  & 4743  & 3778  & 4719 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

[image: I am trying to form such type of table]

Comment: (i) please, provide complete small document, not just table code (i already ask/advice you this in one your previous question!). we haven't any clue about your document layout (text width, text height), used packages, font size etc. all this is essential to help you. (ii) what problem you have with this table? is to wide, to height? (iii) what you try so far to fix your problem (conversion from excel to latex by some program for nice looking table is not sufficient)

Comment: I didn't find to add document (docx) option, so i paste the picture of table below.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tlkuosli3268kt5/Table%207.docx?dl=0

Comment: not a link, please copy code to your question. after while link can can disappear and your question is not complete anymore. this is not my caprice, but the way this site works.

Comment: @lblb, it seems so, however, it seems that op will lost in this nice answer. as i can conclude from table image, he has problems with table philosophy to, not only with `latex`. since he is novice, let help him to make first step in `latex` and table design. for start, how to provide mwe ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- Use landscape mode, say, by loading the `rotating` package and using its `sidewaystable` environment
- Get rid of all -- yes, all -- `\multicolumn{1}{p{4.045em}}{...}` "wrappers". They don't seem to do anything except create havoc
- Structure the header material more clearly
- Insert vertical whitespace (via `\addlinespace` directives) between groups of rows
- Employ `\scriptsize`, for a 30% linear reduction in font size; employ a `tabular*` environment instead of a `tabular` environment
- Align numbers on their decimal markers; provide better distinction between data in parentheses and data not in parentheses. This requires doubling the number of data columns from 10 to 20
- Don't use **bold** for the header cells and the left-hand column since it (a) doesn't improve readability and (b) actually ends up taking a lot of space (relative to non-bold material). For selective emphasis, use `\emph`, e.g. in the subheaders in the left-hand column

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,rotating,array,dcolumn,caption,amsmath}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,a4paper]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\scriptsize % 30% linear reduction in size
\captionsetup{skip=0.333\baselineskip,font=footnotesize}
\caption{Add caption}
\label{tab:addlabel}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt} % make LaTeX figure out intercol. space
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{10}{d{2.5}r} }
\toprule
Variables & \multicolumn{20}{c}{Decisions} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-21}
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Healthcare}
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Social}
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Consumption} 
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Financial} 
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{All} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-9} \cmidrule(lr){10-13} 
\cmidrule(lr){14-17} \cmidrule(l){18-21}  
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{($\text{Parity} \le3$)}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{($\text{Parity} >3$)}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{($\text{Parity} \le3$)}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{($\text{Parity} >3$)}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{($\text{Parity} \le3$)}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{($\text{Parity} >3$)}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{($\text{Parity} \le3$)}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{($\text{Parity} >3$)}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{($\text{Parity} \le3$)}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{($\text{Parity} >3$)}\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{18}{p{0.7\textwidth}}{\emph{Sons} (ref: none)}  \\
At least one son
& 0.156^{***} & (0.059) & 0.088 & (0.228) 
& 0.224^{***} & (0.063) & 0.057 & (0.240) 
& 0.168^{***} & (0.064) & 0.134 & (0.152) 
& 0.020       & (0.068) & 0.175 & (0.214) 
& 0.226^{***} & (0.076) & 0.205 & (0.238) \\
Age
& 0.026^{***} & (0.004) & 0.018^{***} & (0.004)
& 0.030^{***} & (0.004) & 0.024^{***} & (0.005) 
& 0.031^{***} & (0.004) & 0.024^{***} & (0.005) 
& 0.007^{*}   & (0.004) & 0.003       & (0.005) 
& 0.012^{***} & (0.005) & 0.019^{***} & (0.006) \\
Age difference
& 0.016^{***} & (0.005) & 0.002 & (0.005) 
& 0.023^{***} & (0.005) & 0.003 & (0.005) 
& 0.016^{***} & (0.005) & 0.003 & (0.005) 
&-0.004       & (0.005) & 0.001 & (0.005) 
& 0.003       & (0.006) & 0.001 & (0.006) \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{18}{p{0.7\textwidth}}{\emph{Women education} (ref: none)}  \\
Primary
&  0.056 & (0.074) & 0.083       & (0.068) 
&  0.076 & (0.085) & 0.247^{***} & (0.081) 
&  0.036 & (0.086) & 0.044       & (0.075) 
& -0.006 & (0.111) & 0.120       & (0.089) 
&  0.097 & (0.109) & 0.161^{*}   & (0.095) \\
Secondary
& 0.335^{***} & (0.087) & 0.162     & (0.103) 
& 0.239^{***} & (0.077) & 0.030     & (0.103) 
& 0.236^{***} & (0.086) & 0.028     & (0.106) 
& 0.170^{*}   & (0.100) & 0.002     & (0.114) 
& 0.328^{***} & (0.110) & 0.219^{*} & (0.122) \\
Higher
& 0.653^{***} & (0.104) & 0.028       & (0.169) 
& 0.413^{***} & (0.107) & 0.312^{**}  & (0.157) 
& 0.449^{***} & (0.115) & 0.140       & (0.158) 
& 0.182       & (0.128) & 0.181       & (0.158) 
& 0.615^{***} & (0.129) & 0.525^{***} & (0.175) \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{18}{p{0.7\textwidth}}{\emph{Spouse education} (ref: none)} \\
Primary
& -0.014 & (0.089) & -0.235^{***} & (0.075) 
&  0.068 & (0.083) & -0.057       & (0.073) 
&  0.048 & (0.091) & -0.149^{*}   & (0.076) 
&  0.027 & (0.092) & -0.154^{*}   & (0.084) 
&  0.031 & (0.102) & -0.100       & (0.081) \\
Secondary
&  0.017 & (0.073) & -0.079 & (0.077) 
& -0.042 & (0.077) & -0.015 & (0.076) 
& -0.040 & (0.075) & -0.018 & (0.074) 
& -0.107 & (0.077) & -0.068 & (0.071) 
& -0.072 & (0.084) & -0.034 & (0.085) \\
Higher
&  0.024 & (0.085) & -0.035 & (0.097) 
&  0.077 & (0.094) & -0.063 & (0.113) 
&  0.087 & (0.106) & -0.072 & (0.120) 
& -0.110 & (0.097) & -0.103 & (0.108) 
&  0.024 & (0.104) & -0.062 & (0.129) \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{18}{p{0.7\textwidth}}{\emph{Women employed} (ref: none)} \\
Yes
& 0.179^{**}  & (0.080) & 0.205^{***} & (0.058) 
& 0.189^{**}  & (0.080) & 0.231^{***} & (0.068) 
& 0.211^{***} & (0.077) & 0.285^{***} & (0.058) 
& 0.211^{***} & (0.080) & 0.169^{**}  & (0.077) 
& 0.227^{**}  & (0.089) & 0.287^{***} & (0.077) \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{18}{p{0.7\textwidth}}{\emph{Media exposure} (ref: none)} \\
Occasionally
& 0.219^{**}  & (0.086) &  0.044 & (0.082) 
& 0.184^{**}  & (0.083) &  0.041 & (0.084) 
& 0.191^{**}  & (0.082) &  0.063 & (0.102) 
& 0.222^{**}  & (0.102) & -0.007 & (0.081) 
& 0.381^{***} & (0.101) &  0.089 & (0.085) \\
Weekly
& -0.026 & (0.162) & -0.044 & (0.177) 
& -0.173 & (0.164) &  0.170 & (0.185) 
&  0.056 & (0.161) &  0.199 & (0.173) 
& -0.233 & (0.200) &  0.070 & (0.171) 
&  0.039 & (0.194) &  0.223 & (0.219) \\
Daily
& 0.159^{**} & (0.080) & 0.146^{**} & (0.073) 
& 0.136^{*}  & (0.076) & 0.124      & (0.077) 
& 0.161^{**} & (0.073) & 0.184^{**} & (0.081) 
& 0.138      & (0.086) & 0.085      & (0.075) 
& 0.194^{**} & (0.094) & 0.182^{**} & (0.083) \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{18}{p{0.7\textwidth}}{\emph{Family structure} (ref: joint)} \\
Nuclear family
& 0.358^{***} & (0.077) & 0.129^{*}   & (0.071) 
& 0.485^{***} & (0.076) & 0.319^{***} & (0.079) 
& 0.450^{***} & (0.077) & 0.233^{***} & (0.083) 
& 0.101       & (0.084) & 0.049       & (0.102) 
& 0.022       & (0.096) &-0.202^{*}   & (0.114) \\
Household size
& -0.028^{***} & (0.010) & -0.035^{***} & (0.007) 
& -0.042^{***} & (0.010) & -0.039^{***} & (0.007) 
& -0.049^{***} & (0.010) & -0.047^{***} & (0.008) 
& -0.014       & (0.009) & -0.024^{***} & (0.008) 
& -0.031^{***} & (0.009) & -0.043^{***} & (0.010) \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{18}{p{0.7\textwidth}}{\emph{Place of residence} (ref: rural)}
\\
Urban 
& 0.210^{**}  & (0.082) & 0.214^{**} & (0.083) 
& 0.198^{***} & (0.073) & 0.125      & (0.091) 
& 0.220^{***} & (0.071) & 0.129      & (0.087) 
& 0.148       & (0.092) & 0.094      & (0.083) 
& 0.211^{*}   & (0.107) & 0.077      & (0.107) \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{18}{p{0.7\textwidth}}{\emph{Province/Region} (ref: Islamabad)} \\
Punjab
& 0.315^{***} & (0.092) & 0.259^{**} & (0.110) 
& 0.185^{**}  & (0.084) & 0.138      & (0.096) 
& 0.207^{**}  & (0.087) & 0.099      & (0.123) 
& 0.262^{**}  & (0.104) & 0.244^{**} & (0.121)
& 0.254^{**}  & (0.100) & 0.235      & (0.147) \\
Sindh
&  0.167     & (0.102) & -0.099       & (0.120) 
& -0.050     & (0.092) & -0.240^{**}  & (0.105) 
& -0.147     & (0.100) & -0.444^{***} & (0.127) 
& -0.089     & (0.119) & -0.211^{*}   & (0.126) 
& -0.182^{*} & (0.101) & -0.390^{***} & (0.149) \\
KPK region
& -0.279^{**}  & (0.112) & -0.271^{**}  & (0.123) 
& -0.371^{***} & (0.106) & -0.416^{***} & (0.111) 
& -0.317^{***} & (0.110) & -0.426^{***} & (0.137) 
& -0.348^{***} & (0.127) & -0.254^{*}   & (0.133) 
& -0.442^{***} & (0.114) & -0.383^{**}  & (0.153) \\
Gilgit-Balt.
&  0.064       & (0.180) & -0.32^{*}    & (0.186)   
&  0.184       & (0.176) & -0.319^{*}   & (0.185) 
& -0.261^{*}   & (0.133) & -0.564^{***} & (0.175) 
& -0.689^{***} & (0.155) & -0.716^{***} & (0.173) 
& -0.356^{*}   & (0.199) & -0.584^{***} & (0.214) \\
Balochistan
& -0.199       & (0.150) & -0.664^{***} & (0.146) 
& -0.198       & (0.147) & -0.836^{***} & (0.137) 
& -0.219       & (0.151) & -0.906^{***} & (0.164) 
& -0.479^{***} & (0.170) & -0.720^{***} & (0.150) 
& -0.657^{***} & (0.165) & -1.012^{***} & (0.173) \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{18}{p{0.7\textwidth}}{\emph{Economic status} (ref: poorest)} \\
Poorer
& 0.206^{**}  & (0.103) & 0.208^{***} & (0.073) 
& 0.238^{***} & (0.090) & 0.193^{**}  & (0.090) 
& 0.225^{**}  & (0.096) & 0.224^{***} & (0.085) 
& 0.335^{***} & (0.116) & 0.298^{***} & (0.083) 
& 0.206^{*}   & (0.107) & 0.146       & (0.106) \\
Middle
& 0.047      & (0.109) & 0.185^{*}   & (0.105) 
& 0.072      & (0.107) & 0.202^{**}  & (0.094) 
& 0.093      & (0.106) & 0.214^{**}  & (0.089) 
& 0.274^{**} & (0.121) & 0.378^{***} & (0.112) 
& 0.187      & (0.120) & 0.269^{**}  & (0.104) \\
Rich
& 0.041 & (0.119) & 0.186      & (0.123) 
& 0.048 & (0.113) & 0.223^{**} & (0.107) 
& 0.029 & (0.113) & 0.252^{**} & (0.106) 
& 0.180 & (0.134) & 0.281^{**} & (0.121) 
& 0.156 & (0.141) & 0.238^{*}  & (0.127) \\
Richest
& -0.027 & (0.149) & 0.160      & (0.144) 
&  0.070 & (0.128) & 0.236^{*}  & (0.133) 
& -0.030 & (0.130) & 0.271^{**} & (0.134) 
&  0.213 & (0.171) & 0.335^{**} & (0.148) 
&  0.244 & (0.158) & 0.302^{*}  & (0.154) \\
\midrule
Marginal effect
& 0.053^{***} & (0.020) & 0.031 & (0.081) 
& 0.073^{***} & (0.020) & 0.019 & (0.082) 
& 0.054^{***} & (0.020) & 0.046 & (0.053) 
& 0.007       & (0.024) & 0.063 & (0.078) 
& 0.064^{***} & (0.022) & 0.059 & (0.072) \\
Constant
& -1.579^{***} & (0.201) & -0.696^{**}  & (0.309) 
& -1.657^{***} & (0.194) & -0.907^{***} & (0.307) 
& -1.634^{***} & (0.208) & -0.856^{***} & (0.282) 
& -0.498^{**}  & (0.228) & -0.283       & (0.323) 
& -0.291       & (0.209) &  0.012       & (0.374) \\
Observations
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{4906} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{5111}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{4909} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{5126}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{4908} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{5118}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{3789} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{4743}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{3778} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{4719} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Mico for help. Now i am preparing a new table, this table is portrait page, and excluding parity columns. Can you please guide me the code below is correct?

Comment: @RashidJaved - please post new questions as *new questions*, not as "answers" to an existing question. In your new posting, please be sure to state clearly what exactly you are looking to improve.